# TSQL - Insert rows based off range of integers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a SPROC that will take a number as a parameter. I need to take this number and get 2 numbers before it and 2 numbers after it and then insert those into a temp table. For example - The int is 355. I need to write an insert statemenet that inserts 353, 354, 355, 356 and 357. (-2 & +2). I am not entirely sure how to do this. I was thinking maybe a cursor? In C# I would do a for loop but I am not sure the right way to approach in a set language. Thanks!

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLanePrediction]
    @startzip int
AS
BEGIN
    --SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @posnegval int = 2
    DECLARE @TempZips TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Zip INT)

    --INSERT INTO @TempZips (Zip)
    --Some kind of for loop or cursor here?

END
```

The output would create a temp table (@TempZips) with 5 rows. Like so:

```
ID     Zip
1      353
2      354
3      355
4      356
5      357
```

Comment: Your stored procedure takes two numbers as a parameter which pretty much invalidates your explanation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff whatever the solution is, I will repeat it for both start and end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one simple method *based on the question*:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLanePrediction] (
    @onenumber int
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TempZips TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Zip INT)

    INSERT INTO @TempZips (Zip)
        SELECT one_number + v.n
        FROM (VALUES (-2), (-1), (0), (1), (2)) v(n);

END;
```

EDIT:

You can also use a recursive CTE:

```
;WITH n as (
      SELECT -@posnegval as n
      UNION ALL
      SELECT n + 1
      FROM n
      WHERE n < @posnegval
     )
INSERT INTO @TempZips (Zip)
    SELECT @onenumber + n.n
    FROM n
    -- WITH OPTION (maxrecursion 0);  -- only needed if you'll ever have more than 100 numbers
```

Comment: Hm, that could work. But I'd like the variable "@posnegval" to indicate how many integers get added. (To be more dynamic). If it's not possible, I will stick with strictly 2 and just make it work but if not that's still doable.

Answer (score 1):

Just another option using an ad-hoc tally table

```
Declare @I int =355
Declare @R int =2

Select ID = N 
      ,Zip= -1+@I-@R+N
 From ( Select Top ((@R*2)+1) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values n1 ) A
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Zip
1   353
2   354
3   355
4   356
5   357
```